# After assign a pointer to a pointer, why the lvalue become zero

Tags: c

I am writing a function that display the pointer values passed by the caller. 
Because i dont want to mess up the original **arr1,so i assigned a **P to it, then i print it and count it. But then the left hand side,which is arr1 become zero.

Code:

```
  void merge(int **arr1, int **arr2, int **arr3)
    {
    int **p1= arr1;
    int **p2= arr2;
    int **p3= arr3;

    int count;

    printf("%d\n", **arr1);  //this shows the correct value of first element of arr1

    while(**p1)
    {
    printf("%d\n", **p1);
    (*p1)++;
    count++;
    }

    while(**p2)
    {
    printf("%d\n", **p2);
    (*p2)++;
    count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", **arr1);  // this become zero, why??i didn't touch it in my code didn't i?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `arr1` and `p1` point to the same thing.  So if you modify `*p1`, then you'll also modify `*arr1`, because they are the same object.

Comment: @qwrqwr: You modified `*p1`, so it now points somewhere else.  So `**p1` will now be a different object.  The best thing to do is to draw this out on paper.

Comment: If i do (*p)++ i just move on the pointer to next value of **p1 isn't it? 
And the address of **arr1 is not changing during this modification.
so when i print **arr1, it is still on the first element of arr1

Comment: @qwrqwr: `(*p1)++` is the same as `(*arr1)++` in your case.

Comment: So that mean my concept of ** is wrong.
Because when we do :
str[10];
int *p1 = str;

then if i do p1++, i am not affecting the str

Comment: @qwrqwr: No, but printing `*p1` before and after you do `p1++` will give different results.

Answer (score 2):

As you've stated, `**p1` and `**arr1` is the same `int` value that's being pointed to.

Now you have the loop `while(**p1)`, so in order to exit the loop and get down to the `printf` statement, `**p1` must equal 0.

Inside this loop, `p1` is never being modified, `*p1` is, which is the same as `*arr1`, therefore once the loop has exited, `p1` and `arr1` still point to the same position, and `**p1` will equal 0. Therefore `**arr1` must equal the same value as `**p1`, which is 0.

Comment: THanks!
So is there anyway to treat it as like,
p1 point to arr1 and modifying p1 will not affect arr1?

Comment: @qwrqwr: Changing the value of `p1` won't affect `arr1`, however you're never doing that in your code above. ie. `p1++`, `p1 = NULL`, modifying `p1` and not modifying a value you get from dereferencing `p1` won't affect `arr1`. Also, if these arrays being passed to the function are of type `int[]` and not `int[][]`, then you only need a single pointer, not a double one.

Comment: The problem is that my function is taking a pointer that point to a pointer, that why i need a **